# How to overwriting a file on google shared drives

Tags: php, json, google-drive-api, php-curl

I wrote the following function to check if a folder exists in Google shared drives. . How can I do?

```
    public function DeleteFileFromDrive($access_token, $file_id) {         
        $apiURL = self::DRIVE_FILES_URI . $file_id . "?supportsAllDrives=true";
         
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiURL); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token));  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE'); 
         
        $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true); 
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);          
          
        if($http_code != 200 && $http_code != 204){ 
            $error_msg = 'Failed to delete file.';  
            if (curl_errno($ch))
                $error_msg = curl_error($ch);  
            else 
                $error_msg = !empty($data['error']['message'])?$data['error']['message']:''; 
            throw new Exception('Error '.$http_code.': '.$error_msg); 
            return false;
        }
        else 
            return true; 
    }
```

I get this response, even though I am an administrator

> “code”: 403, “message”: “The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.

How can I do it?

I would like to delete a file to be able to load the latest version of the same or, if this is not possible, then be able to overwrite it or, if this is also not possible, move it to another destination (for example a folder called 'trashed.file')

Comment: You want to check the folder, or you want to delete a file, or you want to overwrite a file? Your post says three different things. It's confusing. But the code looks like the intention is to delete

Comment: I had read about this but I hoped there was a solution anyway because in an automatic system the lack of the delete function seems very critical to me. Thank you @ADyson for the confirmation

Comment: But if deleting it's impossible it's possible to overwrite a file? If yes how?